# React and Redux: Dispatching all actions within one function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, axios

In my react application, a user logs in and then directed to his/her dashboard upon authentication. In order to display all the data of the user in the dashboard I have a separate file in which there is a function called getUserData() which dispatches all the actions of the dashboard components and then getUserData() is called within loadUser() so every time the app renders it excutes loadUser(). Is this a good practice and an efficient way to display user data as the app grows larger? Or is there a better way to do it and if so, I would love to know about it. Thank you.

//App.js

```
const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
store.dispatch({type: USER_LOADING});
if(token){
    store.dispatch({type: USER_AUTHENTICATED})
}

class App extends Component{
  componentDidMount(){
    store.dispatch(loadUser());
  }
  render(){
  return(
  <Provider store={store}>
  <div className="App">
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/login" component={LoginPage}/>
        <ProtectedRoute exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard}/>
       
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  </div>
  </Provider>

);
}
};

export default App;
```

//Load user

```
export const loadUser = () => (dispatch, getState) =>{

//dispatch(getNetworkList(config))
  axios.get('/api/user/', setAuthorizationHeader(getState))
    .then(res => {
      dispatch({
      type: USER_LOADED,
      payload: res.data
    })
    dispatch(getUserData())
  })
    .catch(err => {
      dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status));
      dispatch({
        type: AUTH_ERROR
      });
    });
  };
```

//Get user data

```
export const getUserData = () =>(dispatch) =>{
        dispatch(userProfile())
        dispatch(getComments())
        dispatch(getInvites())
        dispatch(getNotifications())
        dispatch(getMessages())
        dispatch(getProjects())
        dispatch(getConnections())
        dispatch(getReply())
        dispatch(getPendingRequests())
        dispatch(getAssignedTasks())
    
};
```

Comment: I think you can write a single Action in reducer which will do he task of all the actions which you've called inside ***getUserData***.

Comment: @tim_woods Your dashboard must be divided into some sort of tabs ... is that right ?

Comment: @Hend El Sahli yes varies different tabs/components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest ou apply what's called **Lazy Loading** ... so if the userProfile is the active-tab upon loading the dashboard, you dispatch `userProfile` action only ...
and fire the rest of the action `onRelatedTabMounted`

Cause most likely, the user is gonna target specific information (comments, invites, ...) ... So there'd be no need to fetch them all on-dashboard-load...